what sci fi story is about planning a spontaneous murder captured on video as his defense
what sci fi story is about planning a spontaneous murder as his defense? In this future, all murders are somehow captured on video for use in trial. A person can get away with murder if it is done in the heat of passion.

My brain goes to "Minority Report". Nicely? Short story? Film?

"Private Eye" by Lewis Padgett.  From this review

“Private Eye” may in a sense be considered an anti-invisibility story. It is set in a future where scientists have learned that light and sound impressions are left behind in the walls of any room, and may be played back like a video recording at any time up to fifty years after an event.


In such a society, with an all-seeing Eye metaphorically watching everything that you see or do — but only if you are suspected of a crime that merits a review of your life — it would seem impossible to commit murder and get away with it.


But one man, Sam Clay, vows to do just that. His girlfriend Bea has just left him for Andrew Vanderman, a successful businessman who Bea claims is everything that Sam is not. Sam decides, then and there at the moment of his breakup with Bea, to murder Vanderman. But he cannot do it immediately and cannot do it in any obvious way, and cannot leave any trace of his intent.

This article quotes at length from the story, allowing me to confirm that crimes of passion were punished considerably less in this society

And the curious upshot of this imbalance came when the act of homicide was declared nonpunishable, unless intent and forethought could be proved. Of course, it was considered at least naughty to fly in a rage and murder someone on impulse, and there was a nominal punishment—imprisonment, for example—but in practice this never worked, because so many defences were possible. Temporary insanity. Undue provocation. Self defense. Manslaughter, second-degree homicide, third degree, fourth degree—it went on like that. It was up to the State to prove that the killer had planned his killing in advance; only then would a jury convict.

